# Find and replace across several files using regular expressions in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, regex, replace, qt-creator

I am writing a C++ library and have just remembered that I need to export each class.

The following code:

```
class MyClass
```

should become:

```
class MY_EXPORT MyClass
```

I have several classes that need this change - is there a way to do this using Qt Creator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [Advanced Search](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-finding.html#advanced-search) feature:

1. `Edit > Find/Replace > Advanced Find > Open Advanced Find...` or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
2. In the `Search Results` window that opens, select an appropriate `Scope` (`Current Project` is probably sufficient in your case).
3. Check `Use regular expressions`.
4. In the `Search for` field, type:

   `^class (.*[^;])$`

   This searches for all class declarations that begin at the start of the line and don't end with a semicolon (to exclude forward declarations).
5. In the `File pattern` field, type:

   `*.h`

   This will ensure the search only happens within header files.
6. Click the `Search & Replace` button. You'll be presented with a list of search results, and the message *"This change cannot be undone."* - now would be a good time to commit your work if you haven't already.
7. Expand each search result to check that the matches are correct. Once you're satisfied, type the following into the `Replace with` field:

   `class MY_EXPORT \1`

   This adds `MY_EXPORT` before the name of each class, using a [numbered backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) to insert the class name captured with the [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) back in step 4.
8. Click the `Replace` button, and you're done.